# Why was 'France' excluded from Henry Lane Wilson's clique during the Mexican Revolution?

Tags: united-states, mexico, revolution, foreign-policy

The book by Friedrich Katz, [*The secret war in Mexico*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0226425894), mentions that the USA minister Henry Lane Wilson organized in part the overthrow of president Madero during the first phase of the Mexican revolution (in Spanish this is known as "La decena trágica").

It is also said that the clique was organized around the central powers at that time, Germany, UK and USA, but for some reason the French were left out. Katz says that the reason is unknown. Is it known nowadays what was this reason?

Of course Mexico had a lot of investment from France, but that was in the dictatorship of Diaz. When Madero took the power as a president, my impression is that the old group (nicknamed "*the scientists*") were not happy with Madero and that much inversion from France was lost during the transition. Thus, from the economical point of view, there does not seem to be a reason why France wasn't interested in joining Wilson and co.

Comment: According to Wikipedia [Ten Tragic Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Tragic_Days) (La decena trágica), *Ambassador Wilson said that he called into consultation, on this and subsequent occasions, only his British, Spanish and German colleagues because they represented the largest interest here, and "the others really did not matter."*